# Difference between using these two default constructors?

Tags: java, constructor, default-constructor

I was able to pass a secret test with my code, which essentially test the code with certain input and expected output. I kept getting an assertion error which stated, expected<1> but was:<0> Until I changed the code from this:

```
public Gunner(){
    this.gunpower = 1;
    this.GunnerStrength = 1;
    this.name = "Default Gunner";
}
```

to

```
public Gunner() {
    this("Default Gunner", 1, 1);
}
```

To illustrate further and to give reference points, here are the codes which preceded the above code:

```
package ship;

public class Gunner {
    private String name;
    private int gunpower;
    private int GunnerStrength;
    private int maxGupower;
    private int maxGunnerStrength;
    private int currentGunpower;
    private int currentGunnerStrength;

    public Gunner(String l_name, int l_gunpower, int l_GunnerStrength) {
        this.name = l_name;
        this.currentGunpower = maxGunpower = l_gunpower;
        this.currentGunnerstrength = maxGunnerStrength = l_GunnerStrength;
    }

    public Gunner(Gunner other) {
        this.name = new String(other.name);
        this.gunpower = new Integer(other.gunpower);    
        this.GunnerStrength = new Integer(other.GunnerStrength); 
        this.maxGunpower = new Integer(other.maxGunpower); 
        this.maxGunnerStrength = new Integer(other.maxGunnerStrength); 
        this.currentGunpower = new Integer(other.currentGunpower);                                              
        this.currentGunnerStrength = new Integer(other.currentGunnerStrength); 
    }
}
```

If someone could please explain the differences between the two codes above it would be much appreciated.

Comment: Depending upon your "test", the first one did not set currentGunpower or currentGunnerStrength. Basically, make sure you initialize all of your instance variables if they are important.

Comment: _"pass a secret test "_ -- what is a secret test?

Comment: what do you mean by "secret test"?  If this is some kind of course I think you would have to clarify with the course instructor.

Comment: @JimGarrison, he'd tell us, but clearly he'd have to gun us down.

Comment: They are like a series of unit tests that test the code with certain inputs and expect certain outputs. For this code I kept getting the error, expected<1> but was:<0> that was until I tried the second code and it worked, still unsure why though.

Comment: `name`, `gunpower`, **`GunnerStrength`**, `maxGupower`, `maxGunnerStrength`, `currentGunpower`, `currentGunnerStrength` -- why is one of these not like the others?

Comment: The quoted code won't compile, you have a field called `maxGupower` (note there's no `n` in that), but your code tries to use `maxGunpower` (with the `n`).

Answer (score 1):

Your original `Gunner()` constructor attempted to *duplicate* the logic of the `Gunner(String,int,int)` constructor, although apparently (as you've passed whatever the "secret test" was), it failed to do so correctly since it filled in different fields: It initialized `gunpower`, `GunnerStrength`, and `name`; but the other constructor initializes `name`, `currentGunpower`, `maxGunpower`, `currentGunnerStrength`, and `maxGunnerStrength`. That's quite a different set of fields.

Your revised `Gunner()` constructor *reuses* the logic of the `Gunner(String,int,int)` constructor, rather than attempting to duplicate it. And so it fills in the fields that `Gunner(String,int,int)` fills in. Presumably the test expected those fields to be filled in.

In general, duplicating logic is a bad idea, because inevitably things change over time, so unless there are convincing arguments to the contrary, *reusing* rather than *duplicating* logic is the way to go.

---

Re your edit:

> I kept getting an assertion error which stated, expected<1> but was:<0>

The default value of an `int` field is `0`, so if you don't initialize or assign another value to the field, it will have the value `0`. So presumably the unit test was checking the value of one of the fields your original `Gunner()` didn't fill in (`currentGunpower`, `maxGunpower`, `currentGunnerStrength`, or `maxGunnerStrength`) but your new `Gunner()` *does* fill in (via `Gunner(String,int,int)`).

---

Side note:

> Difference between using these two default constructors?

There are no *default constructors* in your code. A [*default constructor*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.8.9) is provided by the compiler if you don't define any constructors for the class. Since you *do* define constructors for the class, there is no default constructor.

Your `Gunner()` constructor is a constructor with no formal parameters, sometimes called a *zero-params constructor* or a *zero-args constructor* or a *no-arg(s) constructor* (Java uses "parameter" rather than "argument" to refer to the things you pass into methods and constructors, but they're also commonly called "arguments" informally, hence "args").

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
What I don't understand is why when I googled default constructors only the first version came up. While the second one was much more difficult to unearth. Why is the first default constructor much more common? if from what people tell me the second is much better?

Comment: @FooFighter: There are no "default constructor"s in your code. There is a *zero-parameters* (zero-args) constructor, but no *default* constructor. A *default constructor* is a constructor added by the compiler because you didn't give the class any constructors in the code. Since your class has defined constructors, there is no *default* constructor.

Comment: Well if you want to be all textbook about it sure. So anyway a public Gunner() is technically a zero-parameter constructor, therefore, why wouldn't the first initialize the values exactly like the second?

Comment: It's not "being textbook," it's not surprising that you'd fail to find the information you're looking for if you search for the wrong term. *"why wouldn't the first initialize the values exactly like the second"* Why *would* it? As I said in the answer, your first version doesn't write any value to several fields, so they take their default value, which the test is expecting *not* to be the default value. The second version *does* write non-default values to those fields, by calling another constructor.

Comment: So what's weird is my instructor labeled it as a default constructor, ill be sure to have a talking to with him about this because it certainly confused me when investigating different websites for info.

Comment: @FooFighter: Yeah, unfortunately, sometimes even people who should know what they're doing will use a term incorrectly, sometimes creating quite a lot of confusion.

Comment: Still confused one this. If the idea here was to initialize the values, why didn't saying this.gunpower = 1; work? isn't that setting the value right then and there? And then exactly what is this(x,y,z); is this  type of method here? I did a trial and error and found it out by accident, now I am trying to figure out what it actually means.

Comment: @FooFighter: Please carefully re-read the answer, and the comment above. Setting `gunpower` doesn't set `currentGunpower` or `maxGunpower`. Calling the other constructor, which **does** set those, does set them. (But the other constructor doesn't set `gunpower`; the class has some issues not specifically related to your question, such as why would it need both `gunpower` and `currentGunpower`?)

Comment: Might also be worth noting the common alternative "no-arg".

Comment: @chrylis: Good one, added.